# identify the file extension using java

Tags: java

i have different format files in DB. i want to copy to my local machine.

how can i identify the file format (doc, xls, etc...)

Regards,
krishna

Thanks, for providing suggestions... based on your suggestions i had written the code & i am completed...

please look into my blog.. i posted the code over here...

http://muralie39.wordpress.com/java-program-to-copy-files-from-oracle-to-localhost/

Thank you guys..

Thanks,
krishna

Answer (score 6):

If your files are named according to convention, you can just parse the filename:

```
String filename = "yourFileName";
int dotPosition = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
String extension = "";
if (dotPosition != -1) {
    extension = filename.substring(dotPosition);
}
System.out.println("The file is of type: " + extension);
```

That's the simplest approach, assuming your files are named using some kind of standard naming convention. The extensions could be proprietary to your system, even, as long as they follow a convention this will work.

If you need to actually scan the file to get the format information, you will need to do some more investigation into document formats.

Comment: Be careful if the file has no extension. In that case the `substring` call raises a runtime exception. Better check if `dotPosition` is valid before calling `substring`.

Answer (score 4):

How are the files stored? Do you have filenames with extensions, or just the binary data?

[Mime Util](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/) has tools to detect format both from extensions and from magic headers, but of course that's never 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) apache library.
As Dmitri pointed out however, you may have incorrect results sometimes if detecting mime type from file headers or file extension.